# Web page login not redirecting - php

Tags: php, mysqli

The local version of my login page is working as it should, however the online version does not redirect to the admin page.   What could be possible reasons for this?   Below is the code used to log in to the admin page.   I do not get any errors (unless I put the wrong user / password)  but it does not redirect to the admin page.

**Log in action**

```
<?php
$username = "";

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
  // Process the form

  // validations
  $required_fields = array("username", "password");
  validate_presences($required_fields);

  if (empty($errors)) {
    // Attempt Login

        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        $found_admin = attempt_login($username, $password);

    if ($found_admin) {
      // Success
            // Mark user as logged in
            $_SESSION["admin_id"] = $found_admin["id"];
            $_SESSION["username"] = $found_admin["username"];
     redirect_to ('admin.php');
    } else {
      // Failure
      $_SESSION["message"] = "Username/password not found.";
    }
  }
} else {
  // This is probably a GET request

} // end: if (isset($_POST['submit']))

?>
```

**attempt_login function**

```
function attempt_login($username, $password) {
        $admin = find_admin_by_username($username);
        if ($admin) {
            // found admin, now check password
            if (password_check($password, $admin["password"])) {
                // password matches
                return $admin;
            } else {
                // password does not match
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // admin not found
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**function redirect_to**

```
function redirect_to($new_location) {
        header("Location: " . $new_location);
        exit;
    }
```

I am being given this error:

> [15-Oct-2017 17:03:32 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify
>   header information - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/qvthqtxu/public_html/christasite/includes/session.php:28) in
>   /home/qvthqtxu/public_html/christasite/includes/functions.php on line
>   4

Comment: What is `redirect_to ()`?

Comment: May be you use `header('location: admin.php');` instead of `redirect_to()`

Comment: redirect_to is as function containing header('location: admin.php');

Comment: 1) Check for BOM. 2) Use ```session_start```. 3) Try to use ```header('location: admin.php', true, 301);``` 4) Be sure that your server database has the same entry with login/password for admin as your local database (did you upload database?)

Comment: @user1597430 Never use a 301 for something like this... You don't want your browser to cache a redirect of this type.

Comment: @user1597430 - How do I check for BOM?

Comment: @ChriChri, are you confident that redirect_to is even reached?  What have you done to actually debug this?

Comment: @ChriChri the simplest way for common BOM marker (there are a lot of them actually, visit wiki to find them all) ```function remove_bom($string) { if (substr($string, 0, 3) == pack('CCC', 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf)) { return substr($string, 3); } return $string; }``` <- read your php file, use method above to find/remove BOM marker, rewrite the file.

Comment: @Devon - I am trying to figure out how to debug as it is working perfectly on the localhost but not on the online version :/

Comment: @Devon indeed browsers may cache 301 redirects, however the main idea is to use second param in the ```header``` to override possible garbage for test purposes. In the same time OP didn't provide any info about what actually does not work in his code exactly.

Comment: @user1597430 everything before the redirect is working.  As in - missing username / password - works.  Wrong username/ password also works else {
      // Failure
      $_SESSION["message"] = "Username/password not found.";
    }

Comment: 1. check is sessios_start function call on every page. 2. exit(); or session_write_close(); use any of the function after header location method i.e in your case use in redirect_to function. 3. check session value under redirect_to function

Comment: @ChriChri also I see ```empty($errors)``` in your code without ```$errors``` declaration, are you sure that it exists? Also what's about ```error_reporting``` level? May you insert ```error_reporting(-1);``` in the code after ```<?php``` tag? Are you sure that error displaying is enabled in your php.ini?

Comment: the errors refer to missing username and password mostly -   function errors() {
  if (isset($_SESSION["errors"])) {
  $errors = $_SESSION["errors"];
  $_SESSION["errors"] = null;
  return $errors;
  }   function has_presence($value) {
 return isset($value)  && $value !== "";
}
// * string length
function validate_presences($required_fields) {
 global $errors;
 foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
  $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
  if (!has_presence($value)) {
   $errors[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " can't be blank";
  }
 }
}

Comment: @ChriChri - the browser is not redirecting the user, because output has already been sent. Look at `output started at /home/qvthqtxu/public_html/christasite/includes/session.php:28`.

Comment: Problem solved ... needed to reorder the documents at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem of developers. So better to use HTML redirect.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=./admin.php" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=./admin/" />
```

Don't forget to embed in php code like below.

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=./admin.php\" />";
```